# Concatenation of a trainable and an untrainable variable in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose variable A has shape [123, 64], and variable B has shape [123, 32], then the concatenation of A and B tf.concat([A, B], axis=1) can create variable C with shape [123, 96]

And suppose A is created as **trainable** and B is created as **untrainable**. C is the concatenation of A and B along axis 1.

How about variable C created in this way when optimizing the loss?

1. C is trainable
2. C is untrainable
3. Exactly the first 64 columns of C is trainable, and the last 32 columns of C is untrainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check by yourself if the `C` variable is trainable or not, but first you have to create the variable `C`.

The concatenation operation returns a concat, operation, hence not a variable (so not trainable). Therefore you have to wrap the result into a `tf.Variable` to see if it's trainable or not (and it will because you create a new variable).

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.get_variable("a", (123,64))
b = tf.get_variable("b", (123, 32), trainable=False)
c = tf.concat((a,b), axis=1)
# c is an operation, hence it's not trainable
d = tf.Variable(c)
# d is a Variable created with the content of d, hence trainable
trainable = d.name in [x.name for x in tf.trainable_variables()]
```

Just a quick note. I think it is really important to stress the "(and it will because you create a new variable)" part. C itself will never be a trainable variable nor will any "part" of it be trainable, it is just an intermediate tensor. The only trainable variable is A itself.

Comment: Just a quick note. I think it is really important to stress the "(and it will because you create a new variable)" part. C itself will never be a trainable variable nor will any "part" of it be trainable, it is just an intermediate tensor. The only trainable variable is A itself.

Comment: This is a great note. Can I add it to the answer?

Comment: Of course, that would help everyone stumbling across here.

Comment: copy-pasted your comment. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`C` itself won't be a variable. The trainable variable is still only `A`. So the answer is kind of your 3rd option, but not really since `C` is just an intermediate tensor. Just like if you did something like

```
y = A*x + b
```

TensorFlow does not really care what kind of operation you let `A` flow into, concatenation or what ever. As long as the gradient is defined for the operation TensorFlow will perform automatic differentiation and calculate the gradient for the underlying trainable variable, which is only `A` itself.